# Background color does not cover page

Tags: css, background, alignment, resolution

You can check out my little site [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yotamoo/cr8s8/52/). I have two problems:

1. I use css gradient to color my background. When working with high resolutions (1366*768 for example) only half of the page is painted.
2. My "andale" button on the bottom is not cantered. I've noticed when inspecting the code that the `<div>` that contains the button covers the container, and I don't know why.

Also, if you don't like jsFiddle, here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Rock-paper-scissers</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script src="rps.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    height: 100%;
    font: 100.01% "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#93e1d1), to(#d4c87c));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #93e1d1, #d4c87c); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #93e1d1, #d4c87c);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div#container {
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.InnerLeft {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
div.InnerRight {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
select {
    background: transparent;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 220px;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 0px;
    height: 34px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<img src="header.png">
<div class="InnerLeft">
<img src="uno.png"><br>
<select id="p1" onchange="change('p1','rpsleft')">
<option value=0>Choose your weapon</option>
<option value=1>Rock</option>
<option value=2>Paper</option>
<option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>
<p><img src="rpsL.png" id="rpsleft"></p>
</div>
<div class="InnerRight">
<img src="dos.png"><br>
<select id="p2" onchange="change('p2','rpsright')">
<option value=0>Choose your weapon</option>
<option value=1>Rock</option>
<option value=2>Paper</option>
<option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>
<p><img src="rps.png" id="rpsright"></p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<img src="andale.png" id="andale" onclick="rps(document.getElementById('p1').value,document.getElementById('p2').value)"
onMouseOver="document.getElementById('andale').src='andale2.png'"
onMouseOut="document.getElementById('andale').src='andale.png'">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `html {min-height: 100%;}` , not `height:100%;` because if your page have a long height you will not see all the page, because 100% is the height of the browser

and add `#footer {text-align:center;}` in order to center your image button

**all the code:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Rock-paper-scissers</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script src="rps.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

html {min-height:100%;
 }
body{
    height: 100%;background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#93e1d1), to(#d4c87c));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #93e1d1, #d4c87c); 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #93e1d1, #d4c87c);
    font: 100.01% "Trebuchet MS",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div#container {
    text-align: center;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.InnerLeft {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
div.InnerRight {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
select {
    background: transparent;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 220px;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 0px;
    height: 34px;
}

#footer {text-align:center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<img src="header.png">
<div class="InnerLeft">
<img src="uno.png"><br>
<select id="p1" onchange="change('p1','rpsleft')">
<option value=0>Choose your weapon</option>
<option value=1>Rock</option>
<option value=2>Paper</option>
<option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>
<p><img src="rpsL.png" id="rpsleft"></p>
</div>
<div class="InnerRight">
<img src="dos.png"><br>
<select id="p2" onchange="change('p2','rpsright')">
<option value=0>Choose your weapon</option>
<option value=1>Rock</option>
<option value=2>Paper</option>
<option value=3>Scissors</option>
</select>
<p><img src="rps.png" id="rpsright"></p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<img src="andale.png" id="andale" onclick="rps(document.getElementById('p1').value,document.getElementById('p2').value)"
onMouseOver="document.getElementById('andale').src='andale2.png'"
onMouseOut="document.getElementById('andale').src='andale.png'">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

The fixes:

1. For the 1st issue you have to give your `html` a height also, not just the `body`

   ```
   html { height: 100% }
   ```
2. For the 2nd one you have to clear your floats:

   ```
   #footer {
       clear: both;
       text-align: center
   }
   ```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cr8s8/53/)

Comment: Thanks! can you please tell me why use clear:both? And again thank you, it solved my problem...

Comment: you can read some basics about `clearing floats` [here](http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/)

Comment: `margin:auto` will center the button